# How do add structured/block noise in an image using opencv?

Tags: opencv, noise

For multiview occluded image registration, I have to add structured/block noise in an image. How do add structured/block noise in an image using opencv?

Comment: What have you tried? Share your code.

Comment: First I want to add structured noise in object image, then after finding feature points of noise object image and reference image (without add noise) for multi view image registration.